# Passing Data from View to Controller (codeigniter)

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I am trying to pass some Data using a link from the view to the Controller.

**Controller**:

```
public function details(){
    echo $this->input->post('data_id');
    $data['details'] = $this->wapi_db->details($this->input->post('data_id'));
    $data['latest_news'] = $this->wapi_db->latest_news();
    $data['main_content'] = "category/details";
    $this->load->view('includes/template',$data);
}
```

**View**:

```
<a href=<?php.base_url().'wapi/details?data_id='6'; ?>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could simply us Uri segmen, just like this:

your View Code for href.

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url() ?>wapi/details/6";
```

And to GET the value you passed from view to controller
You should do something like this in your controller

```
    public function details(){

        $data_id = $this->uri->segment(3); //this where you get you value from your link
        ...//rest of your code

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use this link on your view

```
<a href=<?php.base_url().'wapi/details/6'; ?>
```

Then on your controller you just wait for the parameter on the function

```
public function details($data_id){//<- the parameter you want

    $data['details'] = $this->wapi_db->details($data_id);
    $data['latest_news'] = $this->wapi_db->latest_news();
    $data['main_content'] = "category/details";

    $this->load->view('includes/template',$data);

}
```

If your URI contains more than two segments they will be passed to your method as parameters.

From [Codeigniter Controllers Guide](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/controllers.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use

`$this->input->get('data_id')`

because you're passing data via `GET` method.

So your code should be:

```
public function details(){

    echo $this->input->get('data_id');

    $data['details'] = $this->wapi_db->details($this->input->get('data_id'));

    $data['latest_news'] = $this->wapi_db->latest_news();


    $data['main_content'] = "category/details";

    $this->load->view('includes/template',$data);


}
```

Here the docs: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html